# trying to increment instantiate position each time object is created UNITY C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, instantiation

I am wondering how I would set up the following code to increment the instantiate position each time an object is created, so they all line up next to each other. Currently they just all fight for the same location and start dancing with each other in a circle.

```
public void AddUnit(string unitName, Vector3 spawnPoint, Vector3 rallyPoint, Quaternion rotation, Building creator)
    {
        rallyPoint += new Vector3(-10, 0, 0);
        Units units = GetComponentInChildren<Units>();
        spawnPoint += new Vector3(0, 0, -8);
        GameObject newUnit = (GameObject)Instantiate(ResourceManager.GetUnit(unitName), spawnPoint, rotation);
        newUnit.transform.parent = units.transform;
        Unit unitObject = newUnit.GetComponent<Unit>();

        if (unitObject)
        {

            unitObject.SetBuilding(creator);
            if (spawnPoint != rallyPoint)
            {

                unitObject.StartMove(rallyPoint);

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple. Just move this code

```
    spawnPoint += new Vector3(0, 0, -8);
```

to outside the AddUnit() function, to where it is called instead.

The idea being to increment the start position every time you call the function. Here is an example.

```
void Update()
{
    spawnPoint += new Vector3(0, 0, -8);
    AddUnit(unitName, spawnPoint, rallyPoint, rotation, creator);
}
```